# Question about GitHub packages and release

Tags: maven, github, github-actions, github-package-registry

I have a Spring project that I wanted to use as a JAR in another project, for this purpose I decided to use *GitHub packages*. Using GitHub action, whenever any new release is getting created, a new JAR will get publish to GitHub package, but here are my confusions.

So I used `<version>` in my `pom.xml` as `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and made a release with tag `v1.0.0` and released. New package got published and while consuming the JAR I needed to use `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, but I wanted to use **the version which is used while releasing the package to maintain versioning**.

I am not getting what am I missing here. How to use *GitHub release* to publish new version of JAR?

Comment: Below lines need to be more clear:

New package got published and while consuming the JAR I needed to use 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, but I wanted to use the version which is used while releasing the package to maintain versioning.

Answer (score 0):

> How to use GitHub release to publish new version of JAR?

Use GitHub workflow https://docs.github.com/en/packages/quickstart .

Declare configuration/options in `release-package.yml` for generate package when release.

Use Maven SCM plug-in https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/tag-mojo.html . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8901942/3728901

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes I am releasing like this using github actions. and its getting released too. but the version of the dependency is not the one i am creating while creating a release but its coming from the pom.xml of the jar.

Comment: I updated. Use Maven SCM for connection between GitHub source code management with `pom.xml`